# webservices performances

Tags: android

In my application first I am displaying home activity. In home activity I am getting the value from webservice and parsing the value and displaying to the user. From the home activity user click it will display to article display activity. From article display activity if user clicks it will come back to the home activity. It again and again calls web services and parses the value, it takes time.

How do I store the webservice parsed value in firsttime and get the value for all activties? Instead of calling the webservice again and again, can anybody give an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) or [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).